# Combining 2 JavaScript .scroll functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 var stickyTopbar = $('#mainHeader').offset().top;

 $(window).scroll(function() {  
     if ($(window).scrollTop() < stickyTopbar) {
         $('#mainHeader').addClass('topped');
     }
     else {
         $('#mainHeader').removeClass('topped');
     }  
 });


 var stickyTopbar2 = $('#project-content').offset().top;

 $(window).scroll(function() {  
     if ($(window).scrollTop() < stickyTopbar2) {
         $('#close-bar').addClass('off-white');
     }
     else {
         $('#close-bar').removeClass('off-white');
     }  
 });
```

At the moment just the "stickyTopbar" is working. The "stickyTopbar2" doesn't. I have a feeling I should combine both?!

Comment: why don't you combine them?

Comment: It is just weird.. because the second part is not working at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   var stickyTopbar = $('#mainHeader').offset().top;
   var stickyTopbar2 = $('#project-content').offset().top;

     $(window).scroll(function() {  
         if ($(window).scrollTop() < stickyTopbar) {
             $('#mainHeader').addClass('topped');
         }
         else {
             $('#mainHeader').removeClass('topped');
         }; 
         if ($(window).scrollTop() < stickyTopbar2) {
             $('#close-bar').addClass('off-white');
         }
         else {
             $('#close-bar').removeClass('off-white');
         }  
     });
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vhwuvhrd/1/